# share image from URL to other apps

Tags: android, image, kotlin, android-intent, share

Dont make this as duplicate..i have tried every link and i will show following what i have tried till now

i will briefly explain my code-->

fetching image from adapter to activity-->

```
     val bundle: Bundle = getIntent().getExtras()!!

     val imgUrl: String = bundle.getString("image")!!
     val imageUri = Uri.parse(imgUrl)
```

**1-->>>**

full code:--> referred from -->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49011212/sharing-image-using-intent-on-whats-app-getting-error-sharing-failed

```
 val bundle: Bundle = getIntent().getExtras()!!

                val imgUrl: String = bundle.getString("image")!!
                 val imageUri = Uri.parse(imgUrl)

                shareiamge.setOnClickListener {

                    shareImage(imageUri)
                      }
                    private fun shareImage(imagePath: Uri) {
    val sharingIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET)
    sharingIntent.type = "image/*"
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imagePath)
    //sharingIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp"); for whatsapp only
    startActivity(
        Intent.createChooser(
            sharingIntent,
            "Share Image Using"
        )
    ) // for all generic options
}
```

Manifest-->

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ProductDetails.Product_details"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" /> <!-- Send
     action required to display activity in share list -->
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> <!--
      Make activity default to launch -->
            <!-- Mime type i.e. what can be shared with this activity only image and text -->
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

### above code output:-->

when sharing to whatsapp or any app the file format is not supported

**2--->>>refered from this-->>>** [Share text OR Image On Whatsapp in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605491/share-text-or-image-on-whatsapp-in-android)

```
               shareiamge.setOnClickListener {


                    val whatsappIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                    whatsappIntent.type = "image/*"
                    whatsappIntent.putExtra(
                        Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                        imageUri
                    ) //add image path

                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(whatsappIntent, "Share image using"))
               }
```

### above code output:-->

when sharing to whatsapp or any app the file format is not supported

**3-->>>**

```
                val bundle: Bundle = getIntent().getExtras()!!

                val imgUrl: String = bundle.getString("image")!!
                val imageUri = Uri.parse(imgUrl)

                shareiamge.setOnClickListener {


                    val whatsappIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                    whatsappIntent.type = "image/*"
                    whatsappIntent.putExtra(
                        Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                        Uri.parse(res?.body()!!.data.product_images.get(0).image)
                    ) //direct image from retrofit response

                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(whatsappIntent, "Share image using"))
```

### above code output:-->

when sharing to whatsapp or any app the file format is not supported

**4-->>refered from this-->** https://stackoverflow.com/a/25136183/12553303

```
val bundle: Bundle = getIntent().getExtras()!!

                val imgUrl: String = bundle.getString("image")!!
                val imageUri = Uri.parse(imgUrl)

                shareiamge.setOnClickListener {
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey view/download this image")
                    val path: String =
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(imgUrl).toString()
                    val screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path)

                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri)
                    intent.type = "image/*"
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image via..."))
```

### above code output:-->

when sharing to whatsapp or any app --> sharing failed,please try again later

**5-->** but it is only sharing text not image

```
                   val sendIntent = Intent()
                    sendIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, imgUrl)
                    sendIntent.type = "text/plain"
                    startActivity(sendIntent)
```

values in log:-

```
   Log.e("imgUrl",imgUrl)
   Log.e("imageUri", imageUri.toString())

E/imgUrl: http://....../uploads/prod_img/thumb/medium/9dc6234da018916e545011fa1.jpeg
E/imageUri: http://..../uploads/prod_img/thumb/medium/9dc6234da018916e545011fa1.jpeg
```

i want to share an image need help thanks in advance

Comment: "fetching image from adapter to activity" -- it appears that you may be trying to pass a `Uri` between activities. This will not work well, depending on where you get the `Uri` from. Beyond that, use a concrete MIME type (not a wildcard).

Comment: i have used <data android:mimeType="image/*" /> in manifest...is it not enough @CommonsWare and also see my third method where im loading retrofit response

Comment: Well, your `Uri` needs to be a `content` `Uri`. Retrofit is not going to give you that. Moreover, your manifest has nothing to do with this. In your `Intent`, use a concrete MIME type, not a wildcard.

Comment: @CommonsWare if i used like this--> `sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgUrl) sendIntent.type = "image/jpeg"` if i select whatsapp it came back to app with showing `sharing failed please try again later`

Comment: What is the value of `imgUrl`?

Comment: @CommonsWare on debugging--> Bundle[{id=7, image=http://gfsfgdgghv/uploads/prod_img/thumb/medium/da6f8d00dd9f009a543e06312.jpeg}]  im  not putting an original image just an jpeg dummy link ok

Comment: That is not a `Uri`, let alone one with a `content` scheme.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you see my latest edit above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to build content URI from the url. There are several ways to do this.

One way is to build that is download image from url and build URI from the downloaded file.

If you are using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load image from url, then it can be done in following way:

```
Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(photoUrl)
        .into(object: CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {

            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                // do your stuff, you can load placeholder image here
            }

            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {


                val cachePath = File(context.cacheDir, "images")
                cachePath.mkdirs() // don't forget to make the directory
                val stream = FileOutputStream(cachePath.toString() + "/image.png") // overwrites this image every time
                resource.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
                stream.close()

                val imagePath = File(context.cacheDir, "images")
                val newFile = File(imagePath, "image.png")
                val contentUri: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.provider", newFile)

                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                intent.type = "image/*"
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri)
                context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose..."))

            }
        })
```

Don't forget to add `provider` in manifest:

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

and in `provider_paths`

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <cache-path name="cache" path="/" />
</paths>
```

Comment: getting crash -->      Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Try adding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag to intent.

Comment: it is working when activty is loaded but i want to share image when share button is clicked see my code

Comment: also i have loaded that image in my activity by code -->  Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(res?.body()!!.data.product_images.get(0).image).into(
                            imagemain!!
                        );

Comment: noi tried it is not working ...saying in whatsapp file format does not support

Comment: if i dont put your code on onclicklistener then on actvity load it is showing options to share and it is sharing properly on whatsapp also....how can i make this work on shareimage.setonclickliterner?????

Comment: When you put this code in `onClickListener`, it showed error? or sharing options not appeared?

Comment: no error ...sharing options apperared....but if i select one contact and click on send ...it gives toast that file format does not support...i tried on gmail also..it says on taoast couldnt attach file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220205/discussion-between-shafayat-hossain-and-apj123).

Comment: hey it worked..thanks...i missed one thing to remove...

Comment: i have one doubt why above 5 methods are not working? can you tell?

Comment: I've describe it at first line of my answer. Issue is your URI doesn't have any content. That's why those had not worked.